# What is this plank above the Joist pocket for

Tags: framing, brick, masonry, old-house

[image]

Why does this joist have a wooden plank above the pocket embedded in the wall?

Some of the other Joists in the house do not have this.

Comment: What's on the other side of this wall?  I'm wondering if its ventilation ?

Comment: Is this a bottom floor joist, middle floor, or ceiling joist we're looking at? Can you [edit] in a pic of one that doesn't have this?

Comment: @FreeMan this is a floor joist on a double wyth brick house

Comment: @criggie there is brick on the other side this is a double wyth brick house

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity sake in case someone in the future has a similar question. It is a wooden nailer board that was inserted into the brick during construction this was a common thing to do in the 1800s with masonry buildings in order to attach things like trim etc